# User created groups in Joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

I'm looking for a way to make certain users on my site to be able to create groups and to invite other users to their groups. In these groups the users are only able to see their group members articles and other group content. If you are not in a group you will only see the public stuff but as soon as you join a group you will be able to see their articles, menues and other content. You should be able to belong to many groups but only by invitation.

Does anyone know of an extension or solution for this functionality?

I'm using Joomla 1.5

Best regards

Niklas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out [Community Builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/). From the docs:

"Give your members extra privileges and things to do. Make them create content for your website. Personal blogging, image gallery, forum integration (built-in Kunena support), membership groups (using GroupJive component and plugins) and many more additional CB plugins to add even more features and functions."

It's 1.5 native, by the way.

Groupjive can be found [here](http://www.groupjive.org/), and it allows for invitation only groups.